# Nodemailer not sending e-mail after successful stripe payment charge

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, nodemailer

I am trying to send an email to myself after a purchase has been made via stripe. I currently have a personal and business email that I am using for this. I am new to node.js, and I'm confused as to why this is not working.

What makes sense to me is to add this code as an argument to the .then callback. When testing this out locally, the success page renders, however no emails are sent and the two console.log's at the bottom are not being outputted to the console. The following is my app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const stripe = require('stripe')('mystripekey');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const exphps = require('express-handlebars');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')

var app = express();

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
      user: 'myemail@gmail.com',
      pass: 'mypassword'
    }
});

app.engine('handlebars', exphps({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/public`));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
});

app.post('/charge', (req, res) => {
    const amount = 25000;

    stripe.customers.create({
        email: req.body.stripeEmail,
        source: req.body.stripeToken
    })
    .then(customer => stripe.charges.create({
        amount,
        description: 'Advertisement',
        currency: 'usd',
        customer: customer.id
    }))
    .then(charge => {

        // This is where I'm getting confused
        res.render('success')

        var mailOptions = {
            from: req.body.stripeEmail,
            to: 'mybizemail@gmail.com',
            subject: 'A purchase was made',
            text: req.body.stripeEmail + ' made a purchase!'
          };

          transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
            if (error) {
              console.log(error);
            } else {
              console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
            }
          });
    });

});
```

I expected either an error message to be logged or the email sent to be logged but that is not happening. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the node mailer code is never getting called. Try putting the res.render in callback in transporter.sendMail.

Like so:

```
.then(charge => {
    console.log("charge>", charge);
    var mailOptions = {
        from: req.body.stripeEmail,
        to: 'mybizemail@gmail.com',
        subject: 'A purchase was made',
        text: req.body.stripeEmail + ' made a purchase!'
    };
    console.log("mailOptions>", mailOptions);  
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        console.log("error1>", error);
        console.log("info>", info);
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          res.render('error')
        } else {
          console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
          res.render('success')
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If you are debugging, you could set a breakpoint on each of those lines. Another way would be to put console.logs into the code to see where it is going. It is obviously not getting to the existing console.logs. I have modified for you to see.